# SQL alchemy multiple select

Tags: sqlalchemy, aiosqlite

I get an error running this code. The error: The "entities" argument to Select.with_only_columns(), when referring to a sequence of items, is now passed as a series of positional elements, rather than as a list.

Im noob  and now studying python and sqlalchemy, could you assist me and make this code work?

TY in advance!

My code:

```
SessionLocal()
is

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(
    bind=engine,
    class_=AsyncSession,  # Используем асинхронный сеанс
    expire_on_commit=False,
    autocommit=False,
    autoflush=False
)
```

```
async def get_claim_info(claim_id):
    async with SessionLocal() as session:
        try:
            stmt = select(Support.id, Support.Status, Support.Text).filter(Support.id == claim_id)
            result = await session.execute(stmt)

            claim_info = result.fetchone()

            if claim_info:
                claim_text = f"1: {claim_info[0]}\n2: {claim_info[1]}\n3: {claim_info[2]}"
                return claim_text
            else:
                return "none"
        except Exception as e:

            print("Error:", e)
            return "Error"
        finally:
            # Закрываем сессию после выполнения операции
            await session.close()
```

I have tried different ways, for example

```
stmt = select(Support.id, Support.Status, Support.Text).filter(Support.id == claim_id).with_only_columns(Support.id, Support.Status, Support.Text)
or
            stmt = select(Support).filter(Support.id == claim_id).with_only_columns(Support.id, Support.Status, Support.Text)

and
                claim_text = f"1: {claim_info.id}\n2: {claim_info.Status}\n3: {claim_info.Text}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is relatively easy to fix. The API for this SQLAlchemy function has just changed recently.

You didn't provide complete information in your question, so I will have to infer some information from the limited context available, however it should be enough to change this line:

```
with_only_columns(Support.columns.id, Support.columns.Status, Support.columns.Text)
```

You can read more about it here.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.with_only_columns